# Jest fails with (Could not parse CSS stylesheet ...) when using single-spa-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, single-spa

I am using [single-spa-react](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-react/)
to create  a microfrontend. Also i have installed there tailwindcss. All works good.
 To add unit tests i used jest + react testing library. I have the `jest.config.js` file:

```
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageReporters: ['text'],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.css$": ["jest-transform-css", { modules: true }]
    },
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    testRegex: `(__tests__(.*)?(\\.)(spec))\\.(ts)x?$`,
};

export default config;
```

For running the unit tests i am using `yarn jest`. The results are good and all tests passed being green, but above the test coverage in cli i noticed the next error:

```
console.error
      Error: Could not parse CSS stylesheet
          at exports.createStylesheet ... ... ..
```

also there is rendered the next data frm tailwind:

```
'*/\n' +
          '\n' +
          '*,\n' +
          '::before,\n' +
          '::after {\n' +
          '  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */\n' +
          '  border-width: 0; /* 2 */\n' +
          '  border-style: solid; /* 2 */\n' +
          '  border-color: currentColor; /* 2 */\n' +
          '}\n' +
          '\n' +
          '::before,\n' +
          '::after {\n' +
          "  --tw-content: '';\n" +
```

To be able to get rid of the above error i added this in setupTests.js

```
const originalConsoleError = console.error;
console.error = function (message) {
  if (message.startsWith('Error: Could not parse CSS stylesheet')) return;
  originalConsoleError(message);
};
```

adding in `jestConfig.ts` this line: `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],`
...but without success.

 **Question**: Why i get these issues and how to fix them?

Answer (score 2):

I guess its not related to `single-spa-react`, its just a common jest css parsing issue.

The issue usually is related to `jsdom` and how it handles css.

Usual solution is to mock css files, just as all other static, that is non-urgent for testing purposes.

According to the jest documentation, https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules, you can use moduleNameMapper:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
  "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
}
```

Then inside the fileMock.js you can just export an empty object.

You can also use transform:

```
"transform": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
}
```

Then in that fileTransformer.js file you can also just export an empty object.

Other common solution is to use `identity-obj-proxy` https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy in Jest to transform your static for the tests only.

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  transform: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js',
  },
};
```